# What about Union of connected sets?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Please is this prof is correct ?
 Let $\{\Omega_i\}_{i\in I}$ a famille of connected sets such that $$\forall i,j\in I, \Omega_i\cap\Omega_j\neq\emptyset$$
I want to prove that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \Omega_i$ is connected.

If I suppose that $\bigcup \Omega_i$ is not connected then,  there exists two non empty open  sets $A,B$ from $\bigcup \Omega_i$ such that 
$$
\begin{cases}
\bigcup \Omega_i= A\cup B\\
A\cap B=\emptyset
\end{cases}
$$
we have $\forall i\in I, \Omega_i\subset \bigcup_{i\in I}\Omega_i=A\cup B$ then by the connectedness of $\Omega_i$
$$\forall i\in I, [\Omega_i\subset A ~\text{or}~ \Omega_i\subset B]$$

As $\forall i,j\in I, A_i\cap A_j\neq \emptyset$ we deduce that $$\forall I\in A, \Omega_i\subset A~\text{or}~ \forall i\in I,\Omega_i\subset B$$
it follows that $B=\emptyset$ or $D=\emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

**Please if I change the condition 
$$\forall i,j\in I, \Omega_i\cap\Omega_j\neq\emptyset$$
by 
$$
\exists i_0\in I, \Omega_{i_0}\cap \Omega_j\neq \emptyset,\forall j\in I
$$
How to do ?**
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Let $\{\Omega_i\}_{i\in I}$ a famille of connected sets such that $$\exists i_0\in I, \Omega_{i_0}\cap \Omega_j\neq \emptyset,\forall j\in I$$ 
I want to prove that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \Omega_i$ is connected.

If I suppose that $\bigcup \Omega_i$ is not connected then, there exists two non empty open sets $A,B$ from $\bigcup \Omega_i$ such that 
$$ 
\begin{cases} 
\bigcup \Omega_i= A\cup B\\ 
A\cap B=\emptyset 
\end{cases} 
$$ 
we have $\forall i\in I, \Omega_i\subset \bigcup_{i\in I}\Omega_i=A\cup B$ then $\Omega_{i_0}\subset A\cup B$ as it is connected we have $$\Omega_{i_0}\subset A~\text{or} ~ \Omega_{i_0}\subset B$$ if we suppose that $\Omega_{i_0}\subset A$ then $$\forall j\in I, \Omega_{j}\cap A\neq \emptyset $$ by the connectedness of $\Omega_i$ we deduce that $$\forall j\in I, \Omega_{j}\cap B=\emptyset$$ then $$\forall j\in I, \Omega_j\subset A$$ thus $$\bigcup_{j\in I}\Omega_j\subset A$$ so $B=\emptyset$ contradiction in the same way if we suppose that $\Omega_{i_0}\subset B$ we find that $A=\emptyset$

thank you

Comment: Just try doing the same thing; it is very similar.

Comment: @4-ier how to prove with the new condition that $\forall I\in A, \Omega_i\subset A~\text{or}~ \forall i\in I,\Omega_i\subset B$

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes, your proof does seem correct. However, I would still recommend to use the "magic wand" stated below whenever you wish to prove/disprove connectedness. This is because not always is it feasible to find the two non - empty open sets $A$ and $B$ such that all the conditions hold. Moreover, such a definition can be used for (full) spaces but it is really really difficult to use this definition for subspaces. Indeed, we can always use it because all definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a much easier way to prove any given set is connected. Think of it as the "magic wand" for proving connectedness of sets.

Suppose $X$ is a set. Then, it is connected iff every continuous function $f: X \rightarrow \left\lbrace 1, -1 \right\rbrace$ is constant.

Your second case can be easily proven by this fact. Notice that each $\Omega_i$ is connected and hence every continuous function $f_i: \Omega_i \rightarrow \left\lbrace 1, -1 \right\rbrace$ is constant. Now, this is true also for $\Omega_{i_0}$. Now, also observe that $\forall i \in I$, $\Omega_{i_0} \cap \Omega_i \neq \emptyset$ implies that $\exists x_0 \in \Omega_i$ such that it is also in $\Omega_{i_0}$. Now, since $f_{i_0}$ is a constant function, its value at $x_0$ is constant and must be same everywhere in $\Omega_{i_0}$ as well as $\Omega_i$ for every $i \in I$. This is because each $\Omega_i$ is connected. Hence, every continuous function $f : \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \Omega_i \rightarrow \left\lbrace 1, -1 \right\rbrace$ is constant and hence $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} \Omega_i$ is connected.

Comment: Is it the same thing if we suppose that $\bigcap_{I\in I} A_i\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: Not really. $\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \neq \emptyset$ implies that the overall intersection is non - empty, which means that all sets have at least one point in common. Here, it is mentioned that $\exists i_0 \in I$ such that $\forall i \in I$, $A_i \cap A_{i_0} \neq \emptyset$. This means that every set has at least one point common with the set $A_{i_0}$ but that does not mean all the sets have common points with one another.

Comment: can you explain me how to prove with this new condition? and does my proof still correct ?

Comment: Go for the same way. If $\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \neq \emptyset$, then $\exists x_0 \in A_i$ for in fact every $i \in I$. Now, since each $A_i$ is individually connected, every continuous function $f: A_i \rightarrow \left\lbrace 1, -1 \right\rbrace$ is constant and its value must be $f \left( x_0 \right)$. Now, if we consider any continuous function $f: \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \rightarrow \left\lbrace 1, -1 \right\rbrace$, it must again be constant because of the argument above. Hence, $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$ is connected.

Comment: i edited my question can you see it please